# Specific Identity provider for Application in ApiManager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I want to setup custom authentication flow for some applications, registered in Wso2 Api Manager. Say for some applications I want to direct them to federated IDP when they request access token using authorization code or implicit flow. As a key manager I use IdentityServer.

I know that in Identity server I can create Service provider and setup custom authentication scheme for it, e.g. using Federated Authentication. Unfortunetely this service provider can't act as a subscriber for apis in Api Manager. I found [an article](http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/04/28/federated-authentication-for-granting-oauth2-access-token-with-wso2-api-manager-apim/) that describes how to override default auth scheme, but I don't what override defaults.

Is it possible to setup custom IDP only for specific applications **and** avoid tuning default authentication scheme for oauth flows. The reason here is that I still want to use attached userstores for most of the applications but override that behaviour only for some predefined applications.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 APIM 3.2.0 onward it supports [multiple key managers](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/overview/) support. With that, you can create an application binding to a specific key manager you register. You can register a KM from UI and by default, it supports multiple IDPs like okta,oauth0 and WSO2 IS.